# React native fetch API does not work with my local address or any method except for "ngrok"

Tags: react-native, api

This API call work when I use this URL with "Ngrok" server "http://d098a0255d41.ngrok.io/api/GetTrainers" but it doesn't work with my local address and I don't want to keep using the "Ngrok" one forever.
I tried countless methods but they never worked for me, I much appreciate some help or any clues in this!!

```
  fetch("https://192.168.1.228:5001/api/GetTrainers")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {`enter code here`
      setData(responseJson);
      setFullData(responseJson.results);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      setLoading(false);
      setError(err);
    });
}, []);
   
React.useEffect(() => {
  let isMounted = true;
  fetchData()
}, [fetchData]);
```

Comment: try removing https use http instead
http://192.168.1.228:5001/api/GetTrainers

Comment: Still doesn't work :/